# Automatic restart of workflows in node-red

Tags: automation, node-red, restart

I asked this question also in the node-red forum, but there is not much activity (compared to stackoverflow). So I try it here again. The motivation of my question is, that I sometime loose the connection to an OPC-UA-Server that requires restart of the flow to work again. I want to do this automatically in background, because the rare restart of the flow is no big issue - so I can live with it.

There is a thread https://discourse.nodered.org/t/how-to-restart-flows-automatically/12993 that is not really finished or solved.

I implemented the last example, but get error 400, so automatic restart of flow doesn't work. Is there any fool proof description how to do this?

EDIT:

This is the code:

```
    [
    {
        "id": "3623f8cf.b4d2b8",
        "type": "subflow",
        "name": "restart flows",
        "info": "",
        "category": "",
        "in": [
            {
                "x": 40,
                "y": 80,
                "wires": [
                    {
                        "id": "f24fbf79.77a74"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "out": [
            {
                "x": 960,
                "y": 80,
                "wires": [
                    {
                        "id": "cb4d3992.931138",
                        "port": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "env": [
            {
                "name": "user",
                "type": "str",
                "value": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "password",
                "type": "str",
                "value": ""
            }
        ],
        "color": "#FF8888",
        "inputLabels": [
            "Injection"
        ],
        "icon": "node-red/alert.svg"
    },
    {
        "id": "f24fbf79.77a74",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "3623f8cf.b4d2b8",
        "name": "Request Token",
        "func": "var user = env.get('user');\nvar pass = env.get('password');\n\nif(user === undefined || user === null)\n{\n    user = 'adminuser';\n}\nif(pass === undefined || pass === null)\n{\n    pass = 'adminpass';\n}\n\nmsg.payload = {\n    \"client_id\": \"node-red-editor\",\n    \"grant_type\": \"password\",\n    \"scope\": \"*\",\n    \"username\": user,\n    \"password\": pass\n}\nreturn msg;\n\n/*\nmsg.payload = {\n    \"client_id\": \"node-red-editor\",\n    \"grant_type\": \"password\",\n    \"scope\": \"*\",\n    \"username\": \"type or username\",\n    \"password\": \"type your password\"\n}\nreturn msg;\n*/",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "x": 200,
        "y": 80,
        "wires": [
            [
                "3aedf561.e16f4a"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3aedf561.e16f4a",
        "type": "http request",
        "z": "3623f8cf.b4d2b8",
        "name": "Token",
        "method": "POST",
        "ret": "txt",
        "paytoqs": false,
        "url": "http://servername:port/auth/token",
        "tls": "",
        "persist": false,
        "proxy": "",
        "authType": "",
        "x": 390,
        "y": 80,
        "wires": [
            [
                "388fe2f5.639eee"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "388fe2f5.639eee",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "3623f8cf.b4d2b8",
        "name": "Confirm token",
        "func": "// get the status of the request\nvar status = msg.statusCode;\nvar token = '';\nmsg.headers ={};\n\n//let node = feedback;\n\nswitch(status){\n    case 200:\n        node.log(\"Secure restart\");\n        token = JSON.parse(msg.payload);\n        token = 'Bearer '+token.access_token;\n        msg.headers = {\n            \"Authorization\": token,\n            \"Node-RED-Deployment-Type\":\"reload\"\n        }\n        msg.payload =\"\";\n        break;\n    case 204:\n        node.log(\"Secure without restart\");\n        global.set('result','\tSuccess - with no further content');\n        break;\n    case 400:\n        node.warn(\"Bad request\");\n        break;\n    case 401:\n        node.warn(\"Not authorized\");\n        break;\n    case 403:\n        node.warn(\"Forbidden\");\n        break;\n    case 404:\n        node.log(\"Unsecure restart\");\n        msg.headers = {\n            \"Node-RED-Deployment-Type\":\"reload\"\n        }\n        break;\n    case 409:\n        node.warn(\"Version mismatch\");\n        break;\n    case 500:\n        node.error(\"Server Error\");\n        break;\n    default:\n        node.warn(\"Unknown Error\");\n       break;\n}\n\nmsg.payload = \"\";\n\nsetTimeout(function() { node.send(msg) }, 10000);\n\nreturn null;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "x": 580,
        "y": 80,
        "wires": [
            [
                "cb4d3992.931138"
            ]
        ],
        "info": "Restart of Node-Red flows.\nWill check if the action needs security or not.\nNote: if the first 5 attemps return a statuscode 403 'forbidden'\nthen the server will break and only way to recover is then to\nrestart the service"
    },
    {
        "id": "cb4d3992.931138",
        "type": "http request",
        "z": "3623f8cf.b4d2b8",
        "name": "Restart",
        "method": "POST",
        "ret": "txt",
        "paytoqs": false,
        "url": "http://servername:port/flows",
        "tls": "",
        "persist": false,
        "proxy": "",
        "authType": "",
        "x": 780,
        "y": 80,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    }
    ]
```

The settings.js file is as follows:

```
adminAuth: {
    type: "credentials",
    users: [
{
        username: "adminuser",
        password: "adminpass",
        permissions: "*"
    },
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thread you link to was from a year ago and I had [provided an answer](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/how-to-restart-flows-automatically/12993/2?u=knolleary) in the forum that points to the API docs for reloading flows.

I am not aware of a question from you on the forum, but it is so active I may have missed it.

If you are having issues using that API, then please do ask on the forum with an example of what you have tried and what error you are getting.

Comment: The API is not very clear. The last uploaded flow in the thread is clearer, but doesn't work. Obviously it is not sufficient just to call the endpoint of the API. On has to send credentials. But this is not described.

Comment: The link provided very clearly lists  `Authorization` as a required header if authentication is required. And there is a link in the menu on the left of that page that explains how to get a token to do authentication.

Comment: So can I post, what I did and you check it?

Comment: I edited the question to add the code.